# SSH Program with a Teamviewer type login?

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm looking for an SSH program that handles a login like Team Viewer, meaning the server handles the login and makes the connection the computer. I need to do it this way as I'm on a college network and cant connect to my IP but doing it the aforementioned style would work. Also I'm on Windows. Just to clarify I want to set up the SSH program on Windows so I can connect to my Windows computer.

Comment: Where do you see the server residing in this scenario?

Comment: Setup a VPN to some system on the internet, have both computers connect to it.  You could get a cheap VPS, or something.

Comment: My laptop is what I want to act as the server. Its behind a college network which makes this difficult.